# Spring Retry on IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have an integration flow like below and I would like to add a retry for whole the integration flow. Like for any exception in the flow, we do retry and when retries exhausted send it to dead-letter queue.

```
IntegrationFlows
        .from(kinesisInboundChannelAdapter(amazonKinesis(), streamNames))
        .transform(new IssuanceTransformer())
        .route(router())
        .get();
```

Would you please help me out how to configure both retries and dead-letter queue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of integration flow and retry is slightly wrong. The retry it applied for some service call. When we have a complex flow like yours we have also channels between service calls. So, what you can do is something like a retry for each component you think is wrong. For that purpose you need to take a look into the `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` and an `advice()` option of the `ConsumerEndpointSpec`.

If you really have all the logic in a single thread and the same call stack, we really can come up with the solution like "retry the whole sub-flow", but from the Spring Integration perspective it still looks like a service call. For this purpose you need to take a look into the `.gateway()` EIP-method of the `IntegrationFlowDefinition`:

```
IntegrationFlows
    .from(kinesisInboundChannelAdapter(amazonKinesis(), streamNames))
    .gateway(sf -> sf
            .transform(new IssuanceTransformer())
            .route(router())
        , e -> e.advice(requestHandlerRetryAdvice()))
    .get();
```

Comment: I added retry advice as you mentioned above. What I need to do next, is to handle exception after retries exhausted with passing both exception and payload to be able log and send them to dead-letter queue. RetryTemplate recovery callback just provides throwable. how I can pass failed event as well? thank you

Comment: The `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` can be configured with the `RecoveryCallback`, where you can select from the out-of-the-box an `ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer` to use: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: But how I can access the original event that caused the failure?

Comment: The `ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer` does that for you. See its source code. The `determinePayload(Throwable throwable, AttributeAccessor context)` is there for you. So, the `ErrorMessage` to publish to DLQ has what ever you want. On the other hand the `MessagingException` thrown from the Integration components always has a `failedMessage` property for your consideration.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!